# Disable "Mouse battery low" spam notification

Tags: 17.10, mouse, battery, notification, gnome-settings-daemon

Countless times over the past few weeks I have been notified about the low battery in my wireless mouse. Every time it wakes up from sleeping mode and reconnects over Bluetooth I get a notification. I have gotten hundreds of notifications. I do not want them and I do not need them. Yes, battery is low, but at 0% (as reported) it will go on for another week at least. The notification has no timer and will stay visible until I close it.

How do I disable this torture?

[image: screenshot]

Realizing I might sound like a grumpy old man I am not going to replace my batteries that are good for another month as a workaround. I am running Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME Shell. I have no clue what is causing this. Pointers and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**: It turns out the mouse ran for another ten days or so after the initial notification.  With the OS constantly reminding me that it will soon stop working. Wasting fine batteries is not a very good design. People should care about that and have an option to turn the notifications off.

**UPDATE 2018-10-22**: I asked some time ago. The marked correct answer might not apply anymore. It appears to be a bug in the `gnome-settings-daemon`. See the report for updates revolving [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1798166).

Comment: @heynnema You did not read the whole post did you?

Comment: Yes I did read it. Just replace the battery and you'll be good for another 3-6 months. The OS is doing what it was designed to do. You have 0% battery reading. Quit chasing your tail.

Comment: @heynnema Well I've been closing these notifications for about, oh, 6 months now... and still going!  Entirely pointless, and not something that happens in Windows.  The bottom line is these low-powered mice & keyboards have much lower power thresholds than laptop batteries, and so, do not need these excessive warnings for close to half a year of usage... nor do we need condescending comments from people for whom this problem doesn't happen to affect.  Actually it's a confirmed bug; bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201445

Comment: @Domarius Thanks for the update. I edited the question and added a link to the bug report (although, I linked the launchpad report instead).

Comment: @heynnema As of time of writing, the batteries have finally died. So 2 months after I made my comment, previous to which I had been seeing the notification for several months already!  If the "OS is doing what it's designed to do" then this is evidence enough that it is "designed" badly.

For the record, when I boot into Windows, it fades a "battery low warning" for a second and then fades away quickly. Much less intrusive.

Comment: Thanks for this. My Logitech k400+ is at 10%, which I expect to last for a month or two. Constant reminders were a little excessive. :)

Comment: The bug you mentioned in your second update is nearly a year old now, and it's still unassigned, with importance undecided, and with not a damn thing done towards it. Clearly, the folks in the official channels don't care about a bug that is preventing me from using my computer. (It's not just about an annoying popup; that popup is preempting other programs that need to take control of the screen, knocking them out of use.) Has anyone at least figured out what bits of code are actually generating the notification, so I can look into either fixing or removing them?

Comment: It's not in the notification-daemon or notify-osd packages. I know this because I checked, and my system didn't have notification-daemon on it at all, and I removed notify-osd, but it's still happening.

Comment: They should have just added a "do not show this again" option for this device, or something like it that waits till the next recharge cycle, to the notification itself, if they wanted to follow any usability best practice.

Comment: I have a mouse with very low power consumption and my battery is at 10% with those notifications for almost a year. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The solution below includes the notification of the laptop battery as well. Not only the mouse battery. So, as mentioned by @Jetblackstar is not a good option for a laptop or a desktop with multiple peripherals that have their own battery. If you turn off or decrease the `percentage-low`  it will be applied to all the devices with a battery. I hope that this will be resolved on some point.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, I hit the same issue. Reasons are similar; my Logitech M570 is fed on "dead" batteries as it lasts MONTHS on a very low voltage alkaline. So I use batteries in other things and keep the dead ones for my M570.

The best answer I've found was to lower the Power Plugins critical level warning. This way you can customise when it nags.

You need dconf for command line or dconf-editor for the GUI version (for GUI you'll need to do `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`, although that package may not be available for newer versions, so just get `dconf-editor` and its dependencies).

Setting is generically for batteries though, so if you're on a laptop or a UPS then you will be altering the warning levels for those, which may be non ideal.

For [Ubuntu 17.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_17.10_.28Artful_Aardvark.29) (Artful Aardvark) go to org → gnome → settings-daemon → plugins → power. Alter the "percentage-low" setting to what you want. I changed from 10% to 4%.

It is not a perfect answer if you have a laptop, but it is fine for a desktop computer and better than filling landfill with batteries or being nagged.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The popup started to bug me again. `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` contained a lot of goodness.

Comment: This does not work in 18.04. Darn. Notification appears regardless of that setting.

Comment: Same here, also there is no "percentage-low" entry.

Comment: This doesnt work in Mint 19 either :(

Comment: There was no `percentage-low` key on my Gnome 3.30 either and after some time spent Googling this problem it seems there is no other solution out there. Since the notifications were getting really annoying, I just disabled UPower by running `systemctl stop upower` and `systemctl mask upower`. Hopefully, there will be no negative consequences of this action.

Comment: As a note to this, I just did it on Ubuntu 19.04, so if the setting wasn't there in 18.04, it's there now. :)

Comment: I was able to set this setting by running the command `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 4` on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @Wouter I upgraded to 19.04 to try this out but it doesn't work either.

Comment: This setting doesn't do anything on 18.04 for me either, so I solved this by using rechargeable batteries on my M570 and just swapping out the battery when it got "low" (even though as a 1.2V NiMH, it just looks low compared to 1.5V alkaline and could last plenty longer).

Comment: On RHEL/CentOS 8 there is no such option. Instead this can be done by editing `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

Answer (score 44):

For Ubuntu 20.04 and later, go to Settings → *Notifications* → *Power* and toggle off the *Notifications* toggle.

Note that this, however, disables all power notifications.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. The problem is that it disabled ALL the power notifications, not only the ones related to the mouse. So if, for example, my laptop's battery is about to die, I won't get any notification. That's bad.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I JUST WANTED to switch that mouse notification OFF anyhow.

Comment: This is what I need. Since laptops can show the battery life in the top-right corner, I think it does not really matter.

Comment: Works on `19.10` as well.

Comment: Works for 18.04 after latest updates.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for Ubuntu 20. Turning off notification popups does not work, so I had to turn off all Power notifications to get rid of those nasty nag popups.

Comment: It disables the notification popup, but there is still sound every time the mouse turns on. Had to also disable system sounds in the sound settings.

Comment: This is a nice *workaround* on Ubuntu 20.04, however it disables all the power notifications, not only the ones related to mouse and keyboard.

Comment: If it disabled all power messages, this solution is not usable, especially for laptops where low battery warning can be critical (lose data). So, why doesn't Gnome developers just add an option like "Notify low battery" in the Mouse settings? Is it one of the "my way or highway" attitude that they are famous for?

Answer (score 4):

As proposed in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230418/battery-monitor-for-ubuntu-20-04), you can edit the setting of UPower:

`sudo nano /etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

and change the attributes bellow:

```
PercentageLow=5
PercentageCritical=2
```

Then restart the service:

`sudo systemctl restart upower`

This could disable the battery notifications, but still, keep in mind that on a Laptop machine or Desktop PC with multiple peripherals that have their own battery source this will disable the notifications for every device.

So, this will get rid of the annoying notifications, but it does not provide a complete solution.

I can confirm that this works on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. Give it a try, it might work on 17.10 as well.

Comment: Does it apply to only input device batteries, or does it apply to laptop batteries, too? If it is the latter, this solution is unusable, because 5% for a laptop battery is too late. I think 10% is the marginal line where I could save the work or connect the charger.

Comment: Yes, this will affect all types of batteries, including Laptop battery. However, it appears that it doesn't work anymore on Ubuntu 20.04 or the latest. I have set `percentageLow=1`, but still I am getting power notifications on 10%. Something else is handling batteries in 20.04 that I am currently running on a Laptop.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a script that closes the message as soon as it opens (with the delay of 0.5 seconds, it takes time for the message window to open).
This is not perfect, because it closes the last notification window in the window stack. Therefore there is a small chance to close the wrong notification if it appears at almost the same time as the one with the message summary "Mouse battery low".

Dependancies:

```
sudo apt install python-dbus wmctrl -y
```

This one is for xfce. You'll have to tweak it for gnome, if that is what you use.
For xfce next command closes the last notification window:

```
wmctrl -i -c $(wmctrl -lx | awk '/xfce4-notifyd\.Xfce4-notifyd/{print $1}' | tail -n 1)
```

awk filters the window(s) with the window class *xfce4-notifyd*.

For mate-desktop window class is *mate-notification-daemon*, I'm not sure for Gnome.

Change that line for your DE in the script.

Save next script, make it executable and set it to run on startup.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glib
import dbus
import os
import time
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def close_notification(bus, message):
  keys = ["app_name", "replaces_id", "app_icon", "summary",
          "body", "actions", "hints", "expire_timeout"]
  args = message.get_args_list()
  if len(args) == 8:
    notification = dict([(keys[i], args[i]) for i in range(8)])
    if notification["summary"] == "Mouse battery low":
       time.sleep(.5)
       # Adapt next command for your DE
       os.system("wmctrl -i -c $(wmctrl -lx | awk '/xfce4-notifyd\.Xfce4-notifyd/{print $1}' | tail -n 1)")

loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
session_bus.add_match_string_non_blocking("type='method_call',interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify',eavesdrop=true")
session_bus.add_message_filter(close_notification)
glib.MainLoop().run()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with Ubuntu 19.10 (default desktop environment), the notification is not a window listed by `vmctrl -lx` and so this nice script cannot work. Is there any other way to close that notification programmatically?

Comment: I ended up doing this hack, which intercepts D-Bus messages to figure out what notifications to close: https://gist.github.com/eacousineau/63651e498ddc31a7c1478f8638d0fd2e#file-scrub_notifications-py Dunno how robust it is, only tested on Ubuntu 18.04, but mebbe it's useful?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 18.04 on a desktop computer here, so I'm not having issues that laptop could potentially have with that solution.

1. You can test whether what you made is working by restarting upower service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart upower
   ```
2. I managed to solve it by altering upower's config file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf
   ```

I simply commented out whole config, leaving empty 
`<busconfig></busconfig>` tag.

Comment: I have Ubuntu Mate 18.04, and this is the only solution I've found. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Ubuntu 18 here. Laptop battery percentage is gone after doing this. I do not recommend.

Comment: /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf
does not exist here with UBuntu 20.10

Answer (score 3):

Copying the solution from [a blog post](https://wrgms.com/disable-mouse-battery-low-spam-notification/). Use at your own risk.

`disable_mouse_notification.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# https://wrgms.com/disable-mouse-battery-low-spam-notification/

# Check which version you're using
upower --version  
UPOWER_ORIG_VER=`upower --version`

# Check Debian / Ubuntu vs. Arch Linux / Manjaro
OS=`awk -F= '/^ID=/{print $2}' /etc/os-release`  
OS_VER=`awk -F= '/^VERSION_ID=/{print $2}' /etc/os-release | cut -d "\"" -f 2`

if [[ "$OS" == "manjaro" ]]  
then  
    echo "Manjaro detected"
    sudo pacman -S base-devel gtk-doc gobject-introspection git
    PATH_UPOWERD="/usr/lib"
    PATH_UPOWER="/usr/bin"
elif [[ "$OS" == "ubuntu" ]]  
then  
    sudo apt install git gtk-doc-tools gobject-introspection libgudev-1.0-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev autoconf libtool autopoint
    if [[ "$OS_VER" == "20.10" ]]
    then
        echo "Ubuntu version 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) detected"
        PATH_UPOWERD="/usr/libexec"
        PATH_UPOWER="/usr/bin"
    else
        echo "Ubuntu version <= 20.04 detected"
        PATH_UPOWERD="/usr/lib/upower"
        PATH_UPOWER="/usr/bin"
    fi
else  
    echo "Unknown system; this script was only tested on ubuntu and manjaro."
    exit 1
fi

# Download and patch upowerd
#
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower  
cd upower/src  
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guiambros/f2bf07f1cc085f8f0b0a9e04c0a767b4/raw/ef90dfcfa2489bab577bd984a6082abacdf8b0b1/up-device.patch  
patch < up-device.patch  
cd ..  
./autogen.sh
./configure
make

# Install upowerd
#
pushd .  
cd src/.libs  
strip upowerd  
sudo chown root.root upowerd  
sudo mv upowerd ${PATH_UPOWERD}/upowerd-silent  
cd ${PATH_UPOWERD}  
sudo mv upowerd upowerd-original  
sudo ln -s upowerd-silent upowerd  
popd

# Install upower
#
pushd .  
cd tools/.libs  
strip upower  
sudo chown root.root upower  
sudo mv upower ${PATH_UPOWER}/upower-silent  
cd ${PATH_UPOWER}  
sudo mv upower upower-original  
sudo ln -s upower-silent upower  
popd

# Restart upowerd
#
sudo systemctl restart upower

# Compare versions before/after (they will likely be different, but it depends on what your distro packages by default)
echo "upower version BEFORE the update:"  
echo "${UPOWER_ORIG_VER}"  
echo "-------------------------------------"  
echo "upower version AFTER the update:"  
upower --version
```

Result:

```
$ upower --version
```

> upower: symbol lookup error: upower: undefined symbol: up_client_get_devices2

At least the notification is gone immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, two litte modifications:

- git checkout tags/UPOWER_0_99_11 -b notification_patch (for Ubuntu 21.04)
- add keyboards: if ((type == UP_DEVICE_KIND_MOUSE || type== UP_DEVICE_KIND_KEYBOARD) ...

Comment: The blog post seems to be updated so I recommend referring to it. I will keep this post as is because I know it worked for me, but anyone is welcome to edit and update.

Comment: This just worked perfectly for me (with no "symbol lookup error", although I edited the C by hand, not using the supplied patch), in 2024, even on Pop!OS 22.04 (derived from Ubuntu). See my comment on the linked blog post for what I had to change to get it to work on Pop!OS and with modern upowerd.

Answer (score 2):

The solution mentioned in:
https://wrgms.com/disable-mouse-battery-low-spam-notification/
worked for me (on Ubuntu 18.04)

I too got the following error in the final step for the command "upower --version":
upower: symbol lookup error: upower: undefined symbol: up_client_get_devices2

Then I made the following changes as suggested in the comments section, i.e:

1. Replaced "git clone [https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower"](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower%22) with "git clone --single-branch --branch UPOWER_0_99_7 [https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower"](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower%22) (since my upower version was 0.99.7)
2. Installed 'intltool' using "sudo apt-get install intltool" before running "./autogen.sh"

After incorporating these changes, the error is gone and so is the mouse battery power notification!
Thank you Gui Ambros!!

Comment: I think he updated the script that automates it.  I just tried with `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` and `GNOME 3.36.8` and just used the `wget....bash` script command and after 6 minutes, it was patched and solved.   All that for a stupid mouse alert....but anyway it's gone now.