# How to disable "Mouse battery low" notification in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mouse, battery, notification

How to disable "Mouse battery low" notification in Ubuntu 20.04? This notification is spam and pops up all the time and does not go away until you close it. It covers a portion of the screen that is important. It breaks up the flow of work and greatly diminishes work efficiency.

There needs to be a solution for this problem. It is a Problem. A Big Problem.

Not being able to turn of this notification is not acceptable.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: of course you have changed the mouse batteries

Comment: My mouse can run on "dead" batteries until they fail completely, which takes months. There are leds on the side of the mouse that show the battery level. When it gets very low, it goes down several leds and then, finally, the final led turns from green to red. At that point, I can still continue for about a month. I use all the batteries from other devices around the house/work that get too low to operate and use them in the mouse, to do my part of save the landfills.

Comment: There are TWO Ubuntu twenties versions: 20.04 and 20.10. If you think the difference is so great it will hamper my quest for a solution, you shouldn't even comment, especially such a useless comment.

Comment: Seems related/duplicate to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1071406/349837) an [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/985963/349837) questions and [this gnome-settings-daemon](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/108) bug

Answer (score 3):

This is probably happening because your mouse is entering and exiting it's sleep mode.

You can turn off this notification by going into **Settings -> Notifications -> Power** and adjusting these settings. You can turn them off completely or just turn off the notification popups. If you have a UPS this might also turn off those notifications too, but I am not 100% sure since I haven't tested it.

I also found [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8ciyLFrG-s) describing the steps I explained above.

If you are of the hacker type you can try somethings like this:

https://wrgms.com/disable-mouse-battery-low-spam-notification/

Comment: I tried and thought one of the solutions worked, but it did not. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.10. I disabled both Power and Solaar notifications, and they still keep coming.

Answer (score 1):

The most logical solution I've found is to lower the Power Plugins Critical Level warning. This way you can decide when the system will warn you about low battery levels.

> **Warning:**
> This will affect all low-battery messages, not just the ones for your mouse.

You will want to get `dconf-editor` and configure when the system will warn you about low power levels:

1. open a terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`)
2. run `sudo apt install dconf-tools`
3. open the application and go to Org ⇢ Gnome ⇢ Settings Daemon ⇢ Plugins ⇢ Power
4. Change the "Percentage Low" setting to something that works better for you, such as 5%

Keep in mind that this affects *all* low-battery messages. So, if you're using a notebook and you're away from a power outlet, you may not see the message until it's too late.

Comment: Matigo,Thanks I did try all of that before posting and nothing changes the battery popup. It just refuses to stop. I used the dconf-editor and turned off everything that said notification and battery, just to see and nope, the notification just keeps on popping up.
Maybe for people that have a single monitor and watch YouTube videos all day it isn't a problem. I have four, large, 4k panels open and typically about 10+ applications running. I'm trying to work and this popup box is just relentless. I have to move the cursor a Meter, yes, a physical meter (1.00 M) to close that box sometimes.

Comment: I meant to say thank you very much at the end there, but ran out of characters. lol. Thank You Very Much!